# Modelica 4.0.0 multibody animation : How to read .stl files?

Tags: animation, modelica, openmodelica

I built a multibody model with Modelica 3.2.3, where I gave shape to all bodies involved linking the 3D model in stl format to each part.

I've recently updated to Modelica 4.0.0 and I've noticed a problem in reading the stl files:
The simulation has completed succesfully but at the end  an error message has appeared, saying there are no plugins to read stl files, so I can't see the animation anymore.

Have anyone encountered this problem yet and knows how to fix it?

Since the initial opening of the model, a message appears and seems there are problems with some libraries compatibility.
I press "Unload all & Reload Robot_TX2_90L_Corning" to go ahead.
[image: Error window]

At the end of the simulation the error messages are like this (one for each part in the model)
[image: Error message]

In the part parameter configuration, under the "Animation" label, I write the stl file directory path in the shapeType field, but it doesn't work.
[image: Parameter window]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't use C++ tag [tag:STL] irrelevant to the file extension! Read its description carefully!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are using OMEdit 1.21+, as animations were [broken](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/9503) in 1.20.

For example, the stl in this model did not animate in 1.20 but does in 1.21+:

```
model stlsFixed
  inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world annotation(    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape bodyShape(m = 10, r = {0.5, 0, 0}, r_CM = {0.25, 0, 0}, shapeType = "file://C:/absolute/path/to/stl.stl")  annotation(    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {30, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.FreeMotion freeMotion annotation(    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-10, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(world.frame_b, freeMotion.frame_a) annotation(    Line(points = {{-40, 0}, {-20, 0}}));
  connect(freeMotion.frame_b, bodyShape.frame_a) annotation(    Line(points = {{0, 0}, {20, 0}}));
annotation(    Diagram(coordinateSystem(initialScale = 0.08)),    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end stlsFixed;
```